# How to draw poly lines by link ids on HERE map?

Tags: here-api

I have a program which calculates an optimal route based on some objective function. I would like to show the calculated route on the map using the link IDs of the selected links. Is there a way to show poly-lines on the map using Link IDs? (or maybe add a layer based on links IDs?)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the Link ID comprises of ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By link ID, I mean the link ID that we can get from  LINK_FC1...5 or ROAD_GEOM_FC1...5

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but might be useful for other : If using HERE Advanced Data Sets API, then the layer ROAD_GEOM_FC1..5 would provide the shape of a link, ofcourse the layer still have to be requested as tiles and the tiles need to be parsed to get the shape corresponding to a link ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-tile.html))

e.g : https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC1&level=9&tilex=537&tiley=399

For calculating the tilex and tiley values, you can either use the index endpoint

e.g : https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/index.json?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}layer=ROAD_GEOM_FCn&attributes=LINK_ID&values=576452737

or use the formula (if latitude,longitude and Functional class are known)

```
      tile size = 180° /2level [degree]
      tileY = trunc((latitude + 90°) / tile size)
      tileX = trunc((longitude + 180°) / tile size)
```

if you have already the link information from ROAD_GEOM_FC1..5 layer, then see please example how to show some link on the map [e.g. link id 16778251](https://jsfiddle.net/cbsax31f/1/)